# Link href on border of a <td> in a <table>

Tags: html

In HTML I'm creating a table and make the whole cells in each row clickable. The cells are linked to a page with more details to each bill.

The cells in each row are a `<a href ...>`. The hyperlink on each cell are working fine, but not on the border.

Sadly I'm not allowed to show images here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHPOf.png

To change the cursor-arrow to cursor-pointer I already did this:

```
.borderCursor:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

But it's just optical.

I made dat fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/otenmoten/s8reyktm/

I expect to click on the border of a cell and then redirected to the details page.

How to do?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I used the fiddle. What's problem?

Comment: I refer you to the first link in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the kindly note. Further I will do.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution with Thymeleaf:

```
<tr th:onclick="|location.href = '@{...}'|" class="dataRow">
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    ..............
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use box-shadow like this:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
```

Make sure you add this style to the anchor tag

Comment: Yes, you can style as you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @Zohaib's comment, you can add below to keep the space inside `<a>`

```
.borderCursor a {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
.makeBorder {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.borderCursor:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
td{
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td >
        <a class ="makeBorder borderCursor" href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--1--]</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--2--]</a>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <a href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--3--]</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--4--]</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--5--]</a>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <a href = "www.google.de">KLICK ME [--6--]</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you do want add padding for td u can remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it like this:

```
<td onclick="location.href ='https://www.page.com'">
```

Comment: Works, thank you! But it does'nt work with Thymeleaf <td th:onlick="@{...}>.

Comment: Update: We working on a solution that the redirect via Thymeleaf will work. I will update here.

Comment: This introduces major accessibility problems (it renders it inaccessible to keyboard and screen reader users). Don't do this.

Comment: @OtenMoten — It is possible to spot horrible flaws in answers without writing a better one oneself. It would also be hypocritical of me to post an answer because  (as I pointed out in a comment on the question) it doesn't meet the minimum standards for a SO question.

Comment: Then, this is not a horrible flaw. It is the one and only solution because no one can provide better one. Therefore, it's not good nor bad, it's working.